# How to Reallocate/Resize a 3d array to fit into a new size c++

Tags: c++

So for a project I have i need to create a function to 'Resize' the first dimension of a dynamically allocated 3d array of shorts, the function cant alter the original data and must only alter the first dimension of the array.

3darray[alter this][stays the same][stays the same]

The variables passed into the function are the pointer that points to the 3d array, the old size, and the new size.

Ive tried this:

```
void reallocShort3d(short ***&ptr, size_t oldSize, size_t newSize)
{
    short *** temp;

    temp = (short***) realloc(ptr,(newSize - oldSize) * sizeof(ptr));

    ptr = temp;
}
```

but it does not seem to be working, any idea on where i went wrong and possible solutions?

Thanks

EDIT: I realise that I can't use `realloc` now as th 3d array was created with `new`, we are only given the old and new sizes of the first dimension and the array itself, we are not allowed to use vectors:

```
/**
* @brief reallocates/resizes a 3D array of shorts to fit into a new size. 
* Size here refers to the first dimension. i.e. ptr[size][row][col].
*
* @note after the function executed, the original data in the array must 
* not be altered in any way. That is to say, only the first dimension of 
* ptr may be altered.
*
* @NOTE! this function must work in general
*
* @param ptr is the pointer that refers to the 3D array to be resized.
* @param oldSize is the current total number of elements in the first 
*       dimension of ptr. e.g.   ptr[this amount here][row][col]
* @param newSize is the new size that ptr will have after the function 
* has been executed.   ptr[the new amount here][row][col]
*/
```

SECOND EDIT:

Heres the code used to allocate the 3d array:

```
ptr = new short**[2];

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    ptr[i] = new short*[12];
    for (int j = 0; j < 12; ++j)
    {
        ptr[i][j] = new short[numDaysinMonth(j)];
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `ptr` really allocated using `malloc`? Or using `new`?

Comment: In C++ you don't. You use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead. Don't strive to be a[three-start programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer), being called that is *not* a compliment.

Comment: You shouldn't use `malloc()` in C++. Use `new` instead. In addition, try to use standard library facilities. They are more useful than you think.
Edit: You should consider using `std::vector< std::vector< std::vector< T > > >`

Comment: Well, **if** the memory was allocated with malloc (why?), you should write `temp = realloc(ptr, newSize * sizeof(*temp));`, check if it's not null and then allocate memory for the other dimensions.

Comment: Also, if you need to use a C-style cast (like you're doing to the result of `realloc`) then you should take a step back and think about what you're doing. While there are places where a `reinterpret_cast` is needed, using C-style casts are always a sign of you doing something you should not be doing.

Comment: @Rakete1111 using `new`

Comment: @JasonLutz Thatt's the problem, you can't `realloc` memory that has been allocated with `new`

Comment: @Rakete1111 ah ok, makes sense, so how would i go about resizing it then? would I just remake a bigger array and copy everyhthing across?

Comment: @JasonLutz Exactly :)

Comment: @Rakete1111 Thanks for all the help :) Just one more question, if we are only allowed to pass the size of the first dimension into the function how would we discover the sizes of the other dimensions to create this new array?

Comment: @JasonLutz I don't think so

Comment: @Rakete1111 Sorry for the questions, i took a small break from c++ and now trying to get back into it :)

Comment: @JasonLutz `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<short>>> arr;...arr.resize(newsize);`  -- This does what you're trying to accomplish.  A 1-line solution. The second and third dimension's data remains, a new set of "first dimensions" is added (if `newsize` > `oldsize`), all without a single call to `new[]` or `malloc`.

Comment: This isn't a good C either. All the point of having `temp` is to test it against `NULL` before assigning to `ptr` to see if `realloc()` succeeded.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I wish we could use vectors but we are not allowed to, the only thing we're allowed to code is the function, which passes a pointer to a 3d array that's already been allocated with `new` the rest of the code is given to us

Comment: @Rakete1111 I've edited my question a bit and you were the most helpful to me last time, mind taking another look? :)

Comment: Can you please post the code which allocates the memory? Also, is your pointer member of a class?

Comment: @Bob__ There are no classes in the program, just a `main.cpp` and a `.h` paired with a `.cpp` that contain the functions. The memory is allocated in another function like this:

Comment: @Bob__ ptr = new short**[2];

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
 ptr[i] = new short*[12];
 for (int j = 0; j < 12; ++j)
 {
  ptr[i][j] = new short[numDaysinMonth(j)];
 }
}

Comment: @JasonLutz Do you have access to the original array? Or is that against the rules?

Comment: @Rakete1111 we have access the the pointer that gets passed to the function, which points to the original array

Comment: @JasonLutz -- What if `realloc` returns NULL?  Your code just assumes that it works.  Also, you're being taught `C`, not `C++`.  As my comment to one of the answers stated -- the only good way to write code like this is to not write code like this.  The `std::vector` (or some other container class) is the only viable solution.  I wonder if your teacher pondered those details, i.e. `new[]` or `malloc` failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the way OP's code allocates the memory, a simple way to resize it is:

```
short ***tmp;

// in OP's code rows = 12 while the inner dimension is the number of days in a month
// so we can use cols = 31

tmp = new short**[newSize];
// copy the old data
for ( size_t i = 0; i < oldSize; ++i ) {
    tmp[i] = ptr[i];
}
// allocate memory for the new data
for ( size_t i = oldSize; i < newSize; ++i ) {
    tmp[i] = new short*[rows];
    for ( size_t j = 0; j < rows; ++j ) {
        tmp[i][j] = new short[cols];
    }
}
delete[] ptr;
ptr = tmp;
```

**EDIT**

The comment of @PaulMcKenzie points out a major flaw in this code. In C++, operator `new` throws an exception when it's unable to allocate the requested memory. If this happens, our options are limited and in most cases the only thing we can do is some clean up and exit the program.

In the following snippet I'll try to rewrite the function with OP's signature (which I personally, don't like) and to avoid the possible memory leaks. This function eventually rethrows a `std::bad_alloc` exception and it is up to the caller to deal with it (which, I'm pretty much sure, OP's code doesn't).

I'd like to remark that a far better practice would be to stick to the Standard Library containers and/or encapsulate all the memory managment in a class, to ensure RAII.

```
void reallocShort3d(short ***&ptr, size_t oldSize, size_t newSize, size_t rows, size_t cols ) {
    short ***tmp = nullptr;
    std::bad_alloc ee;
    try {      
        tmp = new short**[newSize];
        size_t i = 0, j = 0, ii, jj, kk;
        for ( ; i < oldSize; ++i ) {
            tmp[i] = ptr[i];
        }
        for ( ; i < newSize; ++i ) {
            try {
                tmp[i] = new short*[rows];
                for ( j = 0; j < rows; ++j ) {
                    try {
                        tmp[i][j] = new short[cols];
                    }
                    catch ( const std::bad_alloc &e ) {
                        for ( jj = 0; jj < j; ++jj ) {
                            delete[] tmp[i][jj];
                        }
                        delete[] tmp[i];
                        throw e;    
                    }
                }
            }
            catch ( const std::bad_alloc &e ) {
                for (ii = oldSize; ii < i; ++ii) {
                    for ( jj = 0; jj < rows; ++jj ) {
                        delete[] tmp[ii][jj];
                    }
                    delete[] tmp[ii];               
                }
                delete[] tmp;
                throw e;
            }
        }
    delete[] ptr;
    ptr = tmp;
    }
    catch ( const std::bad_alloc &e ) {
        std::cout << "Error: unable to reallocate.\n";
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: The function should work in the general case, i.e. without knowing the size of the 2 other dimensions, I think. At least that's how I understand it.

Comment: Ahh i see, so when you say `tmp[i] = ptr[i]` is copies the 2d array stored in `ptr[i]` over to `tmp[i]` :) Thank you so much for helping me, much appreciated

Comment: @JasonLutz Jup, but `delete[] ptr;` deletes that memory, so the array becomes corrupt

Comment: @Rakete1111 Yes that's right, but I think in the line `tmp[i] = ptr[i];` the original sizes of the second and third dimension are copied over, as far as i understand

Comment: @Rakete111 Yes, but in his code the inner dimension varies in a particular way (the number of days in a month) and that isn't really general.

Comment: @Rakete1111 Isn't it then reassigned using `ptr = tmp;` at the end?

Comment: @Rakete1111 Ahh yes i see, that's right, we cant use other functions

Comment: @JasonLutz Yes, but then the memory allocated is already deleted

Comment: @JasonLutz the line ` tmp[i] = ptr[i];` only copy the pointers.

Comment: As far as i can see, theres no way of resizing without knowing the size of the other two dimensions, and as @Rakete1111 said, this function has to work in general and as such cant use `numDaysInMonth()`

Comment: @JasonLutz To "work in general" it has to know the maximum sizes of rows (12)  and columns (31), you have to pass them to the function and then swap `12` with `rows` and  `numDaysInMonth(j)` with `cols`

Comment: @Bob__ yes this is what I thought, you have to know the other sizes, I will talk to my lecturer about the validity of the function being able to work in general without the sizes of the other two dimensions being passed because it seems impossible to do otherwise

Comment: @Rakete1111 `delete[] ptr;` deallocates the memory reserved for `ptr`, not the one allocated for all the `ptr[i]`, so copying those pointers _before_ deleting `ptr` doesn't corrupt those arrays. I'm "moving" the data without actually copying every element.

Comment: @Bob__ Oh, I see what you mean. Always get that confused :/ Thanks

Comment: I'm not going to rag too much on this solution, but any solution that looks like this lacks one basic thing -- what if `new[]` throws an exception, right in the middle of that loop?  How do you "roll back" the changes made before the exception occurred?  You can't.  That's why using `std::vector` or creating a container class that does proper RAII is the only real way of doing this.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I agree, Thanks for pointing out. I edited the answer just to show how painful this way could became. I hope I haven't messed it up too much.

Answer (score 1):

As alluded to in the comments, the signature of the reallocate function is not sufficient for the general case as one requires knowledge of the `rows`, `cols` and `slices` of the original 3D array to be able to perform reallocation.

So, assuming you can fix the method signature for the general case the following is a possible solution:

```
void reallocate_short_3d_arr(short***& ptr, std::size_t new_rows, std::size_t old_rows,
    std::size_t cols, std::size_t slices) {
    // allocate memory for tmp 3d arr
    short*** tmp = new short**[new_rows];
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < new_rows; ++i) {
        tmp[i] = new short*[cols];
        for (std::size_t j = 0; j < cols; ++j)
            tmp[i][j] = new short[slices];
    }
    // select correct rows for contraction or expansion of ptr
    std::size_t tmp_rows = (new_rows > old_rows) ? old_rows : new_rows;
    // copy all entries from ptr to tmp
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < tmp_rows; ++i) {
        for (std::size_t j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
            for (std::size_t k = 0; k < slices; ++k)
                tmp[i][j][k] = ptr[i][j][k];
        }
    } 
    // delete original ptr memory
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < old_rows; ++i) {
        for (std::size_t j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
            delete[] ptr[i][j];
        }
        delete[] ptr[i];
    }
    delete[] ptr;
    // assign ptr to tmp such that ptr points to reallocated memory
    ptr = tmp;
}
```

One could probably optimise this via using `std::move` to assign the contents of `ptr` to `tmp` instead fairly trivially as the original `ptr` contents is deleted afterwards anyway so it is safe to move it.

Of course, this is all very silly C++ though and could be easily achieved via `std::vector` as follows:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<short>>> vec_3d(rows,
    std::vector<std::vector<short>>(cols, 
        std::vector<short>(slices))); // initialise "3D vector" of dims rows*cols*slices
vec_3d.resize(new_rows); // resize just the rows, leaving slices and columns the same
```